# Add a div after a certain array element in each group

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

PHP:

```
$rows = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arrayByGroup = array();

$id = null;
foreach ($rows as $r) {
  if($id != $r['id_group']) {
    if (!is_null($id)) {
      echo '</div>';
    }
    $id = $r['id_group'];
    echo '<div class="id_group_' . $id . '">';
  }
  echo "<div>".$r["comments"]."<br>Written by ".$r["name"]."</div>";

}
echo '</div>'
```

I've been using the above code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015762/wrap-array-elements-in-divs-based-on-same-value) to group the returned data based on the common values in the `id_group` field. I'm getting this output

```
 <div class="id_group_1"> 
   <div>comment from group 1</div>
   <div>comment from group 1</div>
   <div>comment from group 1</div>
 </div>

 <div class="id_group_2">
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
 </div>
```

Now I want to add a `.more_comments` div after the forth array element in each group, the ideal output should be like this

```
 <div class="id_group_1"> 
   <div>comment from group 1</div>
   <div>comment from group 1</div>
   <div>comment from group 1</div>
   <div class="more_comments">
     <div>comment from group 1</div>
     <div>comment from group 1</div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="id_group_2">
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div>comment from group 2</div>
   <div class="more_comments">
     <div>comment from group 2</div>
     <div>comment from group 2</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I don't know where to put the counter in the code to get that result. The following attempt doesn't wrap the elements based on the grouping. Can anyone show me how to get that output?

```
$rows = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arrayByGroup = array();
$counter = 0;
$id = null;
foreach ($rows as $r) {
  if($id != $r['id_group']) {
    if (!is_null($id)) {
      echo '</div>';
    }
    $id = $r['id_group'];
    echo '<div class="id_group_' . $id . '">';
  }
  echo "<div>".$r["comments"]."<br>Written by ".$r["name"]."</div>";

 if($counter == 4)
 {
  echo "More Comments";
 }
 $counter++;

}
echo '</div>'
```

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE don't write spaghetti code, use template engines for this stuff :(

Comment: @FezVrasta, not familiar with template engines. Can they use this kind of if conditions?

Comment: depending by the one you choose, yes, but even if not, you should prepare the content to serve to your template and the template should not have much logic in it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for displaying some informations you can use some JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var min_comment = 3;

$('.group').each(function(){
    var children = $(this).children();
    if(children.length > min_comment){
        $(this).html('');
        for(var i=0; i<min_comment; i++){
            $(this).append(children[i]); 
        }
        $(this).append('<div class="more-comments"></div>');
        for(var j=min_comment; i!=children.length; i++){
            $(this).find('.more-comments').append(children[i]);
        }
    }        
});    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caboche_maxime/QjDd9/

Just look on this jsfidle. It's should do what you seek